# Importing excel/CSV file data into visible columns in GridView winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, radgridview

I am trying to populate data from any CSV/ Excel file into the gridview. It uploads fine when all the columns are visible. However, I show/hide columns in the grid based on user's choices. So I would like the values that I paste to be populated in the visible columns of the grid only. I am working in winforms. I have included the code I use for pasting the data into grid below

```
    //Code for pasting clipboard data into gridview
  private void PopulateImportGrid()
    {
        char[] rowSplitter = {'\r', '\n'};
        char[] columnSplitter = {'\t'};

        //get the text from clipboard
        IDataObject dataInClipboard = Clipboard.GetDataObject();
        if (dataInClipboard != null)
        {
            var stringInClipboard = (string) dataInClipboard.GetData(DataFormats.Text);
            //split it into lines
            string[] rowsInClipboard = stringInClipboard.Split(rowSplitter, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

            //     grdSiteDetails.DeferRefresh();
            // loop through the lines, split them into cells and place the values in the corresponding cell.
            using (grdSiteDetails.DeferRefresh())
            {
                for (int iRow = 0; iRow < rowsInClipboard.Length; iRow++)
                {
                    grdSiteDetails.Rows.Add(iRow);
                    //split row into cell values
                    string[] valuesInRow = rowsInClipboard[iRow].Split(columnSplitter);
                    //cycle through cell values
                    for (int iCol = 0; iCol < valuesInRow.Length; iCol++)
                    {
                        //assign cell value, only if it within columns of the grid
                        if (grdSiteDetails.ColumnCount - 1 >= iCol)
                        {
                            grdSiteDetails.Rows[iRow].Cells[iCol].Value = valuesInRow[iCol];
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        grdSiteDetails.ColumnChooserSortOrder = RadSortOrder.None;
    }`
```

Answer (score 0):

How the columns are hidden? If you are using the below property. Check for the same property when pasting.

this.dataGridView1.Columns["columnName"].Visible

Comment: The column names are added during design time and the data that I am pasting into the grid will never have the column names to check.

Comment: Can you try before executing the below line, check whether the column in iCol th position is hidden or not. grdSiteDetails.Rows[iRow].Cells[iCol].Value